# many Interfaces heritage in delphi

Tags: oop, delphi, interface

I hope to make some Class D heritage and implements all properties and methods of Interfaces A,B and C. Please help-me with an example in Delphi.

I use Delphi Xe7
**How One class Implement Many Interfaces?**
I'm trying something like:

```
Unit1
Type
   IRefresher = Interface
      ['{B289720C-FFA4-4652-9F16-0826550DFCF9}']
      procedure Refresh;
      function getRefreshed: boolean;
      property Refreshed:Boolean read getRefreshed;
   End;
```

---

```
Unit2
Type
   IRecorder = Interface
      ['{AB447097-C654-471A-A06A-C65CE5606721}']
      procedure Reader;
      procedure Writer;
   end;
```

---

```
Unit3
ICustomer=Interface ['{F49C0018-37DA-463D-B5B4-4ED76416C7D4}']
    procedure SetName(Value:String);
    procedure SetDocument(Value:String);
    function getName:String;
    function getDocument:String;
End;
```

---

```
  Unit4
    Uses Unit1,Unit2,Unit3;
        TGovernmentCustomer = class(TInterfacedObject, ICustomer, IRecorder,
 IRefresher)
  a: String;
   public
{$REGION 'Customer'}
      procedure SetName(Value: String); override;
      procedure SetDocument(Value: String);
      function getName: String; override;
      function getDocument: String; override;
{$ENDREGION}
{$REGION 'Recorder'}
      procedure Reader; override;
      procedure Writer; override;
{$ENDREGION}
{$REGION 'Refresher'}
      procedure Refresh; override; 
      function getRefreshed: boolean; override;
{$ENDREGION}
   End;
```

It not works, because of many errors, such as 'Refresh not found in base class',

Comment: Simply remove the "override" directives.   "override" is used to override a method declared "virtual" in a ancestor class.  None of your 8 methods exist in the ancestor class "TInterfacedObject".

Comment: Oh, thanks, but now I am confused.How to grant that I will not receive an Abstract Error, if I remove override? Have You some idea?

Comment: Your class implements all of the interface methods. You just don't need to specify `override` when implementing interface methods, only `virtual` class methods.  There is no abstract error in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least 3 implementation options for this:

1) virtual and abstract methods. In this case, you cannot instantiate this class and you must override abstract methods in descendant classes. Such methods would look like this:

```
type
  TGovernmentCustomer = class(TInterfacedObject, ICustomer, IRecorder, IRefresher)
    a: String;
  public
    procedure SetName(Value: String); virtual; abstract;
  end;
```

There is no implementation, once the method is abstract.

2) virtual methods. In this case, you can instantiate this class and you may override some virtual methods in descendant classes. Such methods would look like this:

```
type
  TGovernmentCustomer = class(TInterfacedObject, ICustomer, IRecorder, IRefresher)
    a: String;
  public
    procedure SetName(Value: String); virtual;
  end;

  implementation

  procedure TGovernmentCustomer.SetName(Value: String);
  begin
    // do something here. You can also leave it empty
  end;
```

3) Static methods. In this case, you can instantiate this class and you cannot override static methods in descendant classes. Such methods would look like this:

```
type
  TGovernmentCustomer = class(TInterfacedObject, ICustomer, IRecorder, IRefresher)
    a: String;
  public
    procedure SetName(Value: String);
  end;

  implementation

  procedure TGovernmentCustomer.SetName(Value: String);
  begin
    // do something here. This will be the behavior of all instances of this class and descendant classes if they exist
  end;
```

One last note: Case (3) has the best performance. Calling virtual methods on interfaces has a performance penalty that may or may not be relevant in your specific application.

PS: As pointed out by Stefan, my link to another SO question was wrong. However, you can read about performance of virtual methods called through an interface from Andreas Hausladen blog: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2016/05/whats-wrong-with-virtual-methods-called-through-an-interface/

Comment: The SO question you linked to has nothing to do with the virtual method behind interface issue.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right Stefan. I grabbed the wrong answer. I'll see if I can find the correct one later. Thanks.

Comment: Stefan, I though I had a link to a question explaining that, but happens that I can't find it. Anyway, the answer is updated with a link to Andreas Hausladen blog post which explains the reason behind the performance difference. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `override` word from your code as there is no explicit [method binding directive](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Methods#Method_Binding) for the `interface` method implementation. The `override` directive you've used in your code applies just for the `virtual` (`abstract`) or `dynamic` class methods of an ancestor class that are about to be implemented by the current class.

Here's an example that demonstrates a meaning of the `override` directive with a pseudo-abstract class that uses interfaces (sample from your code):

```
type
  ICustomer = interface
  ['{F49C0018-37DA-463D-B5B4-4ED76416C7D4}']
    procedure SetName(Value: string);
  end;

  IRefresher = interface
  ['{B289720C-FFA4-4652-9F16-0826550DFCF9}']
    procedure Refresh;
  end;

  // sort of "abstract" class (not precisely) that does not yet "implement"
  // the methods of the interfaces, only "includes" the interfaces
  TAnyCustomer = class(TInterfacedObject, ICustomer, IRefresher)
  private
    FSomething: string;
  public
    // though the interfaces are "included" as a part of this class, their
    // method implementation is not yet specific (missing implementantion
    // exception is raised only, which is self-explaining, I'd say); that
    // "virtual" directive of the following class methods lets this class'
    // descendants "override" them to write the specific implementation
    procedure SetName(Value: string); virtual;
    procedure Refresh; virtual;
  end;

  // specific implementation of the class defined above; here you "override"
  // the virtual methods of the "abstract" class defined above and implement
  // the specific behavior of the class
  TGovernmentCustomer = class(TAnyCustomer)
  public
    // "override" the ancestor's class method behavior and write a specific
    // implementation (which finally implements some specific functionality
    // here)
    procedure SetName(Value: string); override;
    procedure Refresh; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TAnyCustomer.SetName(Value: string);
begin
  raise ENotImplemented.Create('Ouch! You missed to implement me!');
end;

procedure TAnyCustomer.Refresh;
begin
  raise ENotImplemented.Create('Ouch! You missed to implement me!');
end;

procedure TGovernmentCustomer.SetName(Value: string);
begin
  ShowMessage('I''m a government customer. How can I increase your budget?');
end;

procedure TGovernmentCustomer.Refresh;
begin
  ShowMessage('Tell someone I''m fresh!');
end;
```